# Return Value waits for broadcast receiver?

Tags: java, android, hashset

Let's say I have a timer running at 60 seconds every interval calling for `getBssid()`, does the return value depends on the broadcast receiver to be received first? as my broadcast receiver sets a value into the HashSet, and `getBssid()` is to retrieve the HashSet

getBssid:

```java
static String getBSSID() {

        return TextUtils.join(",",idsSet);
    }
```

broadcast receiver:

```java
 private BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            idsSet.clear();
            List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
                String scanWifi = scanResult.SSID;
                if (scanWifi.startsWith(ConfigurationManager.configuration.getEssidPrefix())) {
                    idsSet.add(scanResult.BSSID);
                }
            }

            wifiUpdates();
        }
    };
```

If so how do I retrieve the HashSet anytime without waiting for the broadcast receiver?

Comment: can u please explain properly from where you call broadcast reciever ?

Comment: @unzila   context.registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
                wifiManager.startScan(); // wifiReceiver is called

Comment: i did a test and realize when i call getBssid() every 60seconds seconds it will wait for broadcast receiver to finish, wifimanager.startscan is running at different interval(e.g do a scan every 40 seconds) using a handler so it keeps scanning

Comment: yes broadcast reciever take sometimes for scanning so you have to wait for it so you can get your value

Comment: so i cant take my value whenever i want even though its not in the broadcast receiver? @unzila

Comment: you can but just you have to wait until broadcast reciever return bssid's

Comment: is there a way i can call getbssid anytime and get its value without waiting for the broadcast receiver? the hashset is updated constantly though

Comment: no there is no other way

Comment: @unzila lets say i do a getter and setter, so when broadcast receiver is received it will set , and when i call for getBssid() , i get, the broadcast receiver is called periodically so it will always set with updateed value, and i will get the latest result that is last set, will this still cause the getBssid to wait for broadcast receiver to set ?

Comment: yes when broadcast reciever get bssid then its set new value to getBssid function